# How to dispatch code blocks to the same thread in iOS?

Tags: ios, asynchronous, sqlite, thread-safety, grand-central-dispatch

**Main aspect of the question:** It's about iOS. Can I somehow dispatch code blocks in a way, that they will all (a) run in background and (b) on the same thread? I want to run some time-consuming operations in background, but these have to be run on the same thread, because they involve resources, that mustn't be shared among threads.

**Further technical details, if required:** It's about implementing an sqlite plugin for Apache Cordova, a framework for HTML5 apps on mobile platforms. This plugin should be an implementation of [WebSQL](http://www.w3.org/TR/webdatabase/) in the means of the Cordova's plugin API. (That means, it's not possible to wrap entire transactions within single blocks, what could make everything easier.)

Here is some code from Cordova's Docs:

```
- (void)myPluginMethod:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand*)command
{
    // Check command.arguments here.
    [self.commandDelegate runInBackground:^{
        NSString* payload = nil;
        // Some blocking logic...
        CDVPluginResult* pluginResult = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_OK messageAsString:payload];
        // The sendPluginResult method is thread-safe.
        [self.commandDelegate sendPluginResult:pluginResult callbackId:command.callbackId];
    }];
}
```

But as far as I know, there is no guarantee, that those dispatched code blocks (see `runInBackground`) will run on the same thread.

Comment: If you use locking so only one thread can access the API at a time isn't that the same? Doesn't it just have to be one at a time rather than a specific one??

Answer (score 21, accepted):

GCD makes no guarantee that two blocks run on the same thread, even if they belong to the same queue (with the exception of the main queue, of course). However, **if you're using a serial queue (`DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL`) this isn't a problem as you then know that there is no concurrent access to your data.**

The man page for `dispatch_queue_create` says:

> Queues are not bound to any specific thread of execution and blocks submitted to independent queues may execute concurrently.

I'm not aware of any way to bind a queue to a specific thread (after all, not needing to care about threads is a major point of GCD). **The reason why you can use a serial queue without worrying about the actual thread is this promise:**

> All memory writes performed by a block dispatched to a serial queue are guaranteed to be visible to subsequent blocks dispatched to the same queue.

That is, a memory barrier seems to be used.

When dealing with threading issues, your main concern is usually to avoid that two threads access something concurrently. If you're using a serial queue you do not have this problem. It usually doesn't really matter *which* thread is accessing your resources. For example, we're using serial queues to manage Core Data access without a problem.

**Edit:**

It seems you really found a rare case where you need to be working on the same thread. You could implement your own worker thread:

- Prerequisites:

  - A NSMutableArray (let's call it `blockQueue`).
  - A NSCondition (let's call it `queueCondition`).
- Create a new NSThread.

  - The thread's method has an endless loop in which it locks the condition, waits for it if the queue is empty (and the "quit" bool is false), dequeues a block and executes it.
- A method that locks the condition an enqueues the block.

Due to the condition, the thread will simply sleep while there's no work to do.

So, roughly (untested, assuming ARC):

```
- (void)startWorkerThread
{
    workerThread = [[NSThread alloc]
        initWithTarget:self
        selector:@selector(threadMain)
        object:nil
    ];
    [workerThread start];
}

- (void)threadMain
{
    void (^block)();
    NSThread *currentThread;

    currentThread = [NSThread currentThread];

    while (1) {
        [queueCondition lock];
        {
            while ([blockQueue count] == 0 && ![currentThread isCancelled]) {
                [queueCondition wait];
            }

            if ([currentThread isCancelled]) {
                [queueCondition unlock];
                return;
            }

            block = [blockQueue objectAtIndex:0];
            [blockQueue removeObjectAtIndex:0];
        }
        [queueCondition unlock];

        // Execute block outside the condition, since it's also a lock!
        // We want to give other threads the possibility to enqueue
        // a new block while we're executing a block.
        block();
    }
}

- (void)enqueue:(void(^)())block
{
    [queueCondition lock];
    {
        // Copy the block! IIRC you'll get strange things or
        // even crashes if you don't.
        [blockQueue addObject:[block copy]];
        [queueCondition signal];
    }
    [queueCondition unlock];
}

- (void)stopThread
{
    [queueCondition lock];
    {
        [workerThread cancel];
        [queueCondition signal];
    }
    [queueCondition unlock];
}
```

---

Untested Swift 5 port:

```
var workerThread: Thread?
var blockQueue = [() -> Void]()
let queueCondition = NSCondition()

func startWorkerThread() {
    workerThread = Thread() {
        let currentThread = Thread.current
        while true {
            self.queueCondition.lock()
            while self.blockQueue.isEmpty && !currentThread.isCancelled {
                self.queueCondition.wait()
            }

            if currentThread.isCancelled {
                self.queueCondition.unlock()
                return
            }

            let block = self.blockQueue.remove(at: 0)
            self.queueCondition.unlock()

            // Execute block outside the condition, since it's also a lock!
            // We want to give other threads the possibility to enqueue
            // a new block while we're executing a block.
            block()
        }
    }
    workerThread?.start()
}

func enqueue(_ block: @escaping () -> Void) {
    queueCondition.lock()
    blockQueue.append(block)
    queueCondition.signal()
    queueCondition.unlock()
}

func stopThread() {
    queueCondition.lock()
    workerThread?.cancel()
    queueCondition.signal()
    queueCondition.unlock()
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that covers most of the cases and already helps me a lot. In the particular case, I've to work with an sqlite database. This database might even be shared among threads, but only as long as any transactions are pending. But that's my problem: The transaction will begin in a first block, several commands will follow in separate blocks and finally the transaction is committed or rolled back in the last block. Sqlite uses thread-spefic locks, while the database is in transaction, so in this case, I've to assure that all blocks really run on the very same thread.

Comment: As I found out later, the [FMDB](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb) library tries to [solve this problem](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb#using-fmdatabasequeue-and-thread-safety). It's a Objective-C wrapper for sqlite, well suited for iOS. They use a serial queue internally, but they state, that all blocks are executed synchronously the callers thread. (I'm wondering why dispatching then...)

Comment: See my edit. I've described a way with which you can implement your own worker thread to which you can dispatch blocks. Nice thing is, Objective-C allows you to treat blocks like objects so you can put them into an array.

Comment: I'm very interested in your statement `For example, we're using serial queues to manage Core Data access without a problem.` From what I read Core Data doesn't like its contexts to be used in different threads. Does this raise a problem for you? e.g., if you use the same context in dispatches to the same queue, but it runs on different threads?

Comment: @ChrisPrince: Core Data has issues with the same context getting used in different threads *concurrently*. It works fine when used in different threads *serially*, that is, no two threads may use the same context at the same time. This is what a serial GCD queue is achieving.

Comment: That's great to know! Thanks very much. I just was seeing statements like `You should not, therefore, initialize a context on one thread then pass it to a different thread.` (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsmanagedobjectcontext) and taking them at face value-- when it looks like that statement should be changed: "You should not, therefore, initialize a context on one thread then pass it to a different thread [for concurrent usage]."

Comment: Great answer... and the "roughly, untested" code looks solid, and translates nicely into Swift. Top marks!

Comment: @DarkDust I'm trying to implement this for Realm as it requires to be accessed from same thread. How do I make a working example in Swift? When is enqueue and stop being called in your code sample? What is `queueCondition`, how is it declared?

Comment: @denis_lor: See update for a Swift version. You probably do not need to call `stopThread()` ever, it's used to shut down the thread. You call `enqueue(_:)` to schedule a block to be executed on the worker thread.

Comment: @DarkDust Thank you very much for the prompt edit! Do you have any example on how can I use it? I used to have `let synchProcessQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "com.app.processQueue", qos: .default)` and then call it like `synchProcessQueue.async { .... }`.

Comment: @denis_lor: You use `enqueue` instead of `DispatchQueue.async`.

Answer (score 2):

In GCD: no, that's not possible with the current lib dispatch.

Blocks can be executed by dispatch lib on whatever thread which is available, no matter to which queue they have been dispatched.

One exception is the main queue, which always executes its blocks on the main thread.

Please file a feature request to Apple, since it seems justified and sound. But I fear it's not feasible, otherwise it would already exist ;)

Answer (score -1):

You can use `NSOperationQueue`. You can make it use just one thread by using method `- (void)setMaxConcurrentOperationCount:(NSInteger)count`. Set it to 1

Comment: Starting from v10.6 [NSOperationQueues are using libdispatch](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/NSOperationQueue_class/Reference/Reference.html). The blocks would still run one after another but not necessarily on the very same thread. This leads to problems with data structures that hold e.g. re-entry locks like sqlite databases do.

Answer (score -1):

Create a serial dispatch queue, and dispatch all the calls to that serial dispatch queue. All the calls will be performed in the background, but sequentially on the same thread.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to perform a selector in Main Thread, you can use

```
- (void)performSelectorOnMainThread:(SEL)aSelector withObject:(id)arg waitUntilDone:(BOOL)wait
```

and if you want to it to perform in background thread

```
- (void)performSelectorInBackground:(SEL)aSelector withObject:(id)object
```

and if you want to perform in any other thread use GCD(`Grand Central Dispatch`)

```
double delayInSeconds = 2.0;
    dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC));
    dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
        //code to be executed on the main queue after delay
    });
```

Comment: Your last example is executing on the main thread, after a delay. Also, I think you missed the point of the OPs question.

Answer (score -1):

You can either use `NSOperationQueue` with a `MaxConcurrentOperationCount` of `1` or go the manual way down the road by using `NSThread` model (rather than Grand Central Dispatch). 
Using the latter I would recommend you to implement a worker-method which runs in a thread and pulls work-packages (or commands) from a queue or a pool that is being feed from outside of the thread. Just make sure you use Locks / Mutex / Synchronisation.

Answer (score -1):

Never tried this but this might do the trick. Use separate properties of `atomic` dispatch queues for each operation.

```
    @property (strong, atomic) dispatch_queue_t downloadQueue;
```

Queue/Thread 1 for first operation

```
    downloadQueue = dispatch_queue_create("operation1", NULL);
```

etc.

Since `atomic` is thread safe, `downloadQueue` should not be accessed by other threads. So it makes sure that there will be only single thread per operation and other threads will not access it.

Comment: Be aware: According to the [iOS Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationQueues/OperationQueues.html), the blocks run one after another, but probably on different threads. My data structures hold thread-specific locks, so in this particular case, it's really important to use the same thread.

Comment: I updated my answer. Check whether it works for you.

Comment: @sleepwalkerfx how can I try this in swift?

Answer (score -2):

Just like this,

```
dispatch_asyn(dispatch_get_current_queue, ^ {
});
```

Comment: For a number of reasons, `dispatch_get_current_queue` will not work as "expected" and thus is deprecated. Anyway, when this code is running on a secondary thread, but has not been dispatched to a dispatch queue, what do you think  `dispatch_get_current_queue()` would return?