# Swift + Async: How to execute a callback on the same thread where it was created?

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, asynchronous

Using the [Async](https://github.com/duemunk/Async) library, a simple pattern to do work on a background thread might look like this:

```
// Assume we start on the main thread

let onResultComplete: (result: ResultType) -> Void = { result in
    Async.main {
        // Code to handle one result at a time on the main thread
    }
}

Async.background {
    doCalculationsThatProduceManyResults(onEachResultComplete: onResultComplete)
}
```

Now consider this scenario, where the code is already being executed on a background thread:

```
// Assume we start on some "unknown background thread"

let onResultComplete: (result: ResultType) -> Void = { result in
    Async.??? {
        // Code to handle one result at a time on the "unknown background thread"
    }
}

Async.background {
    doCalculationsThatProduceManyResults(onEachResultComplete: onResultComplete)
}
```

How can I force the closure `onResultComplete` to be run on the **same** unknown background thread from where I called `Async.background`?

I'm open to any suggestions that use GCD methods.

Comment: Turns out this is impossible, as explained by [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22091859/4621566).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On iOS or macOS, if some code executes on an *unknown* thread or dispatch queue (say: "execution context"), there's no means to reliable obtain some "handle" for it - well, unless this is the main thread.

So, the solution to your problem is to first create or obtain a *known* execution context (aka dispatch queue or thread) and execute your code here. Then, in the continuation (aka completion handler), explicitly dispatch back to this same execution context again and continue with your code.

Comment: The known execution contexts you can create off of the main thread are either 1) a dispatch queue, which will run on multiple unknown threads, or 2) a thread used for a one-off block/closure like [`NSThread.init(target:selector:object:)`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSThread_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSThread/initWithTarget:selector:object:) There is no way to ensure that multiple separate blocks/closures are executed on the same thread. Please correct me if I am wrong!

Comment: @pejalo I fear, no. Suppose some code executes on the main thread. You can verify this with `NSThread.isMainThread`. But you cannot determine, whether this thread is currently used from an arbitrary dispatch queue, which uses another thread some time later when it executes another submitted block. So, the "execution context" is the unknown dispatch queue, and not the main thread. In this case, knowing you are executing on the main thread is not sufficient to establish guarantees about synchronisation constraints (e.g. safely accessing shared variables within this execution context, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Don't call `Async.anything`. Simply run the code in-line (assuming the Async library calls it's completion block on the same thread where the calculations are run.

Your question is specific to the Async library, so you should put that in your title and add a tag for it. (I've never used it, so I don't know the specifics of how it works.)

Comment: Thanks. `Async.background` causes a background thread to be created on which the calculations are run. `onResultComplete` is then called from that background thread, so I need `Async.something` to return execution to the starting thread.

Comment: What do you mean "the starting thread"? The background thread on which the calculations are run, or the thread from which the call to `Async.background` is executed? If the second, there is likely no way to know what thread invoked `Async.background` unless you modify that method to identify and remember the calling thread.

Comment: The second. It seems that you're right. With iOS there's no guarantee of what thread your code is executed on (except the main thread), because even dispatch queues use different threads throughout their lifetime. Thanks again