# swift iOS generic Realm manager

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I am looking to create generic Realm manager to perform `CRUD` operations. I can `addOrUpdate` single object to local db using below code

```
var profileManager: RealmManagerN<Profile>?
self.profileManager?.addOrUpdate(object: value.profile!,
                                                         completion: { error in
                                                            if let err = error {
                                                                print("Error \(err.localizedDescription)")
                                                            } else {

                                                            }
 })
```

But I am facing issue while adding `array` object. I have tried below code

```
var deviceManager: RealmManagerN<Devices>?
self.deviceManager?.addOrUpdate(object: value.devices!,
                                                             completion: { error in
                                                                if let err = error {
                                                                    print("Error \(err.localizedDescription)")
                                                                } else {

                                                                }
                            })
```

Below is my `Devices` model

```
import RealmSwift

class Devices: Object, Decodable {
    @objc dynamic var addedOn: Double = 0.0
    @objc dynamic var category: String? = nil
    @objc dynamic var deviceId = ""
    @objc dynamic var deviceName: String? = nil
    @objc dynamic var deviceType : String? = nil
    @objc dynamic var firmware: String? = nil
    @objc dynamic var isActive: Bool = true
    @objc dynamic var lastUpdate: Double = 0.0
    @objc dynamic var uuDeviceId = ""
    @objc dynamic var model: String? = nil
    @objc dynamic var typeId = 0
    @objc dynamic var userId = 0

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case addedOn = "added_on"
        case category = "category"
        case deviceId = "device_id"
        case deviceName = "device_name"
        case deviceType = "device_type"
        case firmware = "firmware"
        case isActive = "is_active"
        case lastUpdate = "last_update"
        case uuDeviceId = "uu_device_id"
        case model = "model"
        case typeId = "type_id"
        case userId = "user_id"
    }
    override public static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "uuDeviceId"
    }
}
```

> Note: `value.devices` is the `array` of `Devices`

I am getting this error **Cannot convert value of type '[Devices]' to expected argument type 'Devices'**. How can I insert collection?

**EDIT** : This is my `RealmManagerN.swift`

```
import Foundation
import Realm
import RealmSwift

/**
 Realm manager class that reduces the boiler plate needed when creating a realm transaction.
 createOrUpdate, and Delete uses background thread

 - warning: This class assumes that every existing model being passed has a primaryKey set to it
 */
public class RealmManagerN<T> {
    public typealias Completion = ((_ error: Error?) -> Void)
    var realm: Realm?
    var background: RealmThread?

    init(configuration: Realm.Configuration?,
         fileUrl: URL?) {

        background = RealmThread(start: true,
                                 queue: nil)
        background?.enqueue {[weak self] in
            guard let self = self else { return }
            do {
                if let config = configuration {
                    self.realm = try Realm(configuration: config)
                } else if let fileUrl = fileUrl {
                    self.realm = try Realm(fileURL: fileUrl)
                } else {
                    self.realm = try Realm()
                }
            } catch let error {
                fatalError(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
    }
}

extension RealmManager {
    fileprivate func addOrUpdateWithRealm<Q: Collection>(realm: Realm,
                                                         object: Q,
                                                         completion: @escaping Completion) where Q.Element == Object  {
        do {
            try realm.write {
                realm.add(object,
                          update: .error)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    completion(nil)
                }
            }
        } catch (let error) {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                completion(error)
            }
        }
    }

    fileprivate func addOrUpdateWithRealm<T: Object>(realm: Realm,
                                                     object: T,
                                                     completion: @escaping Completion) {
        do {
            try realm.write {
                realm.add(object,
                          update: .error)

                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    completion(nil)
                }
            }
        } catch (let error) {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                completion(error)
            }
        }
    }

    fileprivate func write(rlmObject: Realm, writeBlock:()-> Void) -> Error? {
        do {
            //try to do a realm transaction
            try rlmObject.write {
                writeBlock()
            }
        } catch let error {
            //catch and return the error if occurs
            return error
        }
        //no error
        return nil
    }

    fileprivate func fetch<Q: Object>(condition: String?,
                                      completion: @escaping(_ result: Results<Q>) -> Void) {

        guard let realm = realm else { return }

        // All object inside the model passed.
        var bufferObjects = realm.objects(Q.self)

        if let cond = condition {
            // filters the result if condition exists
            bufferObjects = bufferObjects.filter(cond)
        }

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            //if let safe = bufferObjects.copy() as? Results<Q> {
                completion(safe)
            //}
        }
    }
}

extension RealmManagerN where T: Collection, T.Element == Object {

    /// Add or Update an object to existing Model
    ///
    /// Accept any object that conforms to Collection Protocol,
    /// Takes a closure as escaping
    /// parameter.
    ///
    /// - Parameter object: [Object] to be saved.
    /// - Parameter completion: Closure called after
    ///   realm transaction
    /// - Parameter error: an optional value containing error
    public func addOrUpdate(object: T,
                            completion:@escaping Completion) {

        background?.enqueue {[weak self] in
            guard let self = self else { return }

            guard let realm = self.realm else { return }

            self.addOrUpdateWithRealm(realm: realm,
                                      object: object,
                                      completion: completion)
        }
    }

    //MARK: - File Private
    fileprivate func delete(condition: String?,
                            objects: T,
                            completion:@escaping(_ error: Error?) -> Void) {
        let group = DispatchGroup()
        var error: Error?

        background?.enqueue {[weak self] in
            group.enter()
            guard let self = self else { return }
            guard let realm = self.realm else { return }

            error = self.write(rlmObject: realm, writeBlock: {
                realm.delete(objects)
                group.leave()
            })
        }

        group.wait()
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            completion(error)
        }
    }
}

extension RealmManagerN where T: Object {
    /// Add or Update an object to existing Model
    ///
    /// Accept any object that is a subclass of Object or RealmObject,
    /// Takes a closure as escaping
    /// parameter.
    ///
    /// - Parameter object: Object to be saved.
    /// - Parameter completion: Closure called after
    ///   realm transaction
    /// - Parameter error: an optional value containing error
    public func addOrUpdate(configuration: Realm.Configuration? = nil,
                            object: T,
                            completion: @escaping Completion) {
        background?.enqueue {[weak self] in
            guard let self = self else { return }

            guard let realm = self.realm else { return }

            self.addOrUpdateWithRealm(realm: realm,
                                      object: object,
                                      completion: completion)
        }
    }

    /// Fetches object from existing model
    ///
    ///
    /// - Parameter type: Type representing the object to be fetch, must be
    /// subclass of Object
    /// - Parameter condition: Predicate to be used when fetching
    ///   data from the Realm database (Optional: String)
    /// - Parameter completion: Closure called after the
    ///   realm transaction
    /// - Parameter result: An Array of Object as result from
    ///   the fetching
    public func fetchWith(condition: String?,
                          completion:@escaping(_ result: Results<T>) -> Void) {

        background?.enqueue {[weak self] in
            guard let self = self else { return }

            self.fetch(condition: condition,
                       completion: completion)
        }
    }

    /// Deletes an object from the existing model
    ///
    ///
    /// - Parameter configuration: Realm Configuration to be used
    /// - Parameter model: A string of any class NAME that inherits from 'Object' class
    /// - Parameter condition: Predicate to be used when deleting
    ///   data from the Realm database (Optional: String)
    /// - Parameter completion: Closure called after the
    ///   realm transaction
    /// - Parameter error: an optional value containing error
    public func deleteWithObject(_ object: T?,
                                 condition: String,
                                 completion:@escaping(_ error: Error?) -> Void) {

        background?.enqueue {[weak self] in
            guard let self = self else { return }

            self.delete(object: object,
                        condition: condition,
                        completion: completion)
        }
    }

    ///MARK: FilePrivates
    fileprivate func delete(object: T?,
                            condition: String?,
                            completion:@escaping(_ error: Error?) -> Void) {
        guard let realm = realm else { return }

        let group = DispatchGroup()
        var error: Error?

        background?.enqueue {[weak self] in
            group.enter()
            guard let self = self else { return }

            if object == nil {
                var fetched = realm.objects(T.self)

                if let cond = condition {
                    // filters the result if condition exists
                    fetched = fetched.filter(cond)
                }

                error = self.write(rlmObject: realm, writeBlock: {
                    realm.delete(fetched)
                    group.leave()
                })
            } else {
                if let object = object {
                    error = self.write(rlmObject: realm, writeBlock: {
                        realm.delete(object)
                        group.leave()
                    })
                }
            }
        }

        group.wait()
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            completion(error)
        }
    }
}
```

Below is code for `RealmThread`

```
import Foundation

/// FIFO. First-In-First-Out guaranteed on exactly same thread.
class RealmThread: Thread {

    typealias Block = () -> ()

    private let condition = NSCondition()
    private(set) var queue = [Block]()
    private(set) var paused: Bool = false

    /**
     Designated initializer.
     - parameters:
     - start: Boolean whether thread should start immediately. Defaults to true.
     - queue: Initial array of blocks to add to enqueue. Executed in order of objects in array.
     */
    init(start: Bool = true, queue: [Block]? = nil) {
        super.init()
        // Add blocks initially to queue
        if let queue = queue {
            for block in queue {
                enqueue(block: block)
            }
        }
        // Start thread
        if start {
            self.start()
        }
    }

    /**
     The main entry point routine for the thread.
     You should never invoke this method directly. You should always start your thread by invoking the start method.
     Shouldn't invoke `super`.
     */
    final override func main() {

        // Infinite loops until thread is cancelled
        while true {
            // Use NSCondition. Comments are from Apple documentation on NSCondition
            // 1. Lock the condition object.
            condition.lock()

            // 2. Test a boolean predicate. (This predicate is a boolean flag or other variable in your code that indicates whether it is safe to perform the task protected by the condition.)
            // If no blocks (or paused) and not cancelled
            while (queue.count == 0 || paused) && !isCancelled  {
                // 3. If the boolean predicate is false, call the condition object’s wait or waitUntilDate: method to block the thread. Upon returning from these methods, go to step 2 to retest your boolean predicate. (Continue waiting and retesting the predicate until it is true.)
                condition.wait()
            }
            // 4. If the boolean predicate is true, perform the task.
            // If your thread supports cancellation, it should check this property periodically and exit if it ever returns true.
            if (isCancelled) {
                condition.unlock()
                return
            }

            // As per http://stackoverflow.com/a/22091859 by Marc Haisenko:
            // Execute block outside the condition, since it's also a lock!
            // We want to give other threads the possibility to enqueue
            // a new block while we're executing a block.
            let block = queue.removeFirst()
            condition.unlock()
            // Run block
            block()
        }
    }

    /**
     Add a block to be run on the thread. FIFO.
     - parameters:
     - block: The code to run.
     */
    final func enqueue(block: @escaping Block) {
        // Lock to ensure first-in gets added to array first
        condition.lock()
        // Add to queue
        queue.append(block)
        // Release from .wait()
        condition.signal()
        // Release lock
        condition.unlock()
    }

    /**
     Start the thread.
     - Warning: Don't start thread again after it has been cancelled/stopped.
     - SeeAlso: .start()
     - SeeAlso: .pause()
     */
    final override func start() {
        // Lock to let all mutations to behaviour obey FIFO
        condition.lock()
        // Unpause. Might be in pause state
        // Start
        super.start()
        // Release from .wait()
        condition.signal()
        // Release lock
        condition.unlock()
    }

    /**
     Cancels the thread.
     - Warning: Don't start thread again after it has been cancelled/stopped. Use .pause() instead.
     - SeeAlso: .start()
     - SeeAlso: .pause()
     */
    final override func cancel() {
        // Lock to let all mutations to behaviour obey FIFO
        condition.lock()
        // Cancel NSThread
        super.cancel()
        // Release from .wait()
        condition.signal()
        // Release lock
        condition.unlock()
    }

    /**
     Pause the thread. To completely stop it (i.e. remove it from the run-time), use `.cancel()`
     - Warning: Thread is still runnin,
     - SeeAlso: .start()
     - SeeAlso: .cancel()
     */
    final func pause() {
        // Lock to let all mutations to behaviour obey FIFO
        condition.lock()
        //
        paused = true
        // Release from .wait()
        condition.signal()
        // Release lock
        condition.unlock()
    }

    /**
     Resume the execution of blocks from the queue on the thread.
     - Warning: Can't resume if thread was cancelled/stopped.
     - SeeAlso: .start()
     - SeeAlso: .cancel()
     */
    final func resume() {
        // Lock to let all mutations to behaviour obey FIFO
        condition.lock()
        //
        paused = false
        // Release from .wait()
        condition.signal()
        // Release lock
        condition.unlock()
    }

    /**
     Empty the queue for any blocks that hasn't been run yet
     - SeeAlso:
     - .enqueue(block: Block)
     - .cancel()
     */
    final func emptyQueue() {
        // Lock to let all mutations to behaviour obey FIFO
        condition.lock()
        // Remove any blocks from the queue
        queue.removeAll()
        // Release from .wait()
        condition.signal()
        // Release lock
        condition.unlock()
    }
}
```

Comment: There's not enough code here to understand what you're asking. What is value.devices? What do your models look like. What does `.addOrUpdate` do? Please clarify the question and we'll take a look!

Comment: @Jay Thanks for your reply. Please check my edit

Comment: The issue is with your .addOrUpdate function but seeing as that's not in the question, what the specific issue is remains a mystery. It seems a little odd that the function is called `.addOrUpdate(object` noting that the word `object` is singular (not plural) but for object you're passing in is an entire *array of objects*? `value.devices is the array of Devices`

Comment: Have you checked this ? https://github.com/markcdb/RealmManager/blob/master/RealmManager/RealmManager.swift

Comment: It contains two extension methods  for `addOrUpdate`. One is accepting Object & other one is Collection. So I am unable to call collection method.

Comment: Understood. That is an offsite library and for assistance please reach out to to the developer as the issue/question is with their library, not Realm. See [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). *Questions asking for support for offsite resources are off-topic for Stack Overflow. Direct your questions to the relevant organisation instead.* I would suggest crafting your own Realm manager as it's not too complex. Also, the function should be passed an object, not an array/collection according to the docs - passing a collection would not make sense.

Comment: I don't think this question is off topic. I just confused why My `RealmManager` class didn't show `addOrUpdate` method for collection? I can only find single `Object` method. RealmManager has two extension method i.e. `extension RealmManager where T: Collection, T.Element == Object` &  `extension RealmManager where T: Object`

Comment: It's off topic because there is no such thing as RealmManager in Realm. That's part of a third party library. *my class didn't show addOrUpdate method for collection* is because **it doesn't have one**. The only addOrUpdate functions are this one `addOrUpdate(object:` and this one `addOrUpdate(configuration:`. See the third party library code you linked in your comment above. For further assistance, please reach out the the developer of that library or update the tag on your question accordingly.

Comment: That I also know, there is no such thing in Realm. I am creating Generic manager for Realm `CRUD` operation. And the link I have provided is the example.

Comment: Understood. The issue here is that you're asking us to assist you with code that is not included in your question. Also, you say your creating a Generic manager but the provided links are to a third party library that you're asking about. So is it your manager or the third party library? Please take a moment and review [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Clarify and update your question and we'll take a look!

Comment: @Jay Check my code.

Comment: ouch. That's way too much code to process here on SO and is a copy and paste of another developers library, not your own work. You may have overlooked the *minimal* part of [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). More importantly though, I've answered the question several times above; let me highlight this answer again **the class doesn't show an addOrUpdate method for a collection because it doesn't have one**. So there is no function `addOrUpdate(collection:)` to be called in that library.

Comment: `So there is no function addOrUpdate(collection:) to be called in that library` - Please check extension method `extension RealmManagerN where T: Collection, T.Element == Object`. It's look like you haven't checked my code.  Anyways it's look like you also don't know how to solve it. Thanks

Comment: That's not the meaning. Please take a look at the error **Cannot convert value of type '[Devices]' to expected argument type 'Devices'** and compare it to the function you're trying to call.

Comment: And how do you update your objects using that manager? If you update the object and try to call .addOrUpdate, the app will crash because you are updating outside write transaction.